# pre-loading image sequence on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image-preloader

here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a .png image sequence, consisting of 80 frames each of them about 120 KB. 
I want the user to scroll through the sequence and everything works perfectly owhen I do it offline. 
As soon as it's online it takes much more time of course to request the images from the server and thus leading to a slow and choppy animation.

I already tried to put all the images 9999 px left and top so the site loads all the images from the beginning, which didn't work as I expected. 
Spriting was another approach I came across, however, my images are quite big so the spriting image would be huge. To be accurate, they're 1920 x 1080.

Is there another approach I could try?

Comment: Images will always take time to load. If you want the image to be ready when the page load, the best way would be putting a `<script>` inside `<head>` that preload the image and force the browser to wait until those images are loaded before showing the page. Like so: `<script>var img = new Image(); img.src = "your img url";</script>`

Comment: Thanks for that idea, didn't see the obvious.